# IBMQ job was not run immediately after it was sent during my reservation

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime, ibm-quantum-devices, ibm-q-experience

I got a problem when I sent a job during my reservation on ibmq_guadalupe. My job was in queue position 1 for almost 11 hours. Why was the job not run immediately after it was sent?

Is there any solution to fix the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about quantum computing. Please contact IBM cloud tech support.